# jQuery .text() multiple elements same class

Tags: jquery, text, each

I'm attempting to use .text() on multiple (unknown number of) elements on a page.

Consider:

```
<ul>
    <li class="myClass">element1</li>
    <li class="myClass">element2</li>
    <li class="myClass">element3</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$('.myClass').text();
```

Will return the first element's text "element1".

I came across the following while looking around:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(index, obj)
{
   // do something
});
```

However, this simply query returns each full elements like:

```
<li class="myClass">element1</li>
<li class="myClass">element2</li>
<li class="myClass">element3</li>
```

I need to return all element's text such as:

"element1"
"element2"
"element3"

Thanks!

Comment: simply concat the result inside `.each`

Comment: could try `result += ""+$(obj).text()`; or `$("ul").text();`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```js
var x =[];
$('.myClass').each(function(index, obj)
{
  x.push($(this).text());
});

console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="myClass">element1</li>
    <li class="myClass">element2</li>
    <li class="myClass">element3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Using this as my answer, as an array made this much easier.
Thanks wit_peter!

Answer (score 21):

You can use `map()` to retrieve a specific property of a group of elements and place them in an array:

```
var textValues = $('.myClass').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

From there you can work with the array to create the string as you need, for example, using `join()`:

```
console.log(textValues.join(', ')); // = 'element1, element2, element3'
```

```js
var textValues = $('.myClass').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(textValues.join(', ')); // = 'element1, element2, element3'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="myClass">element1</li>
  <li class="myClass">element2</li>
  <li class="myClass">element3</li>
</ul>
```

---

**March 2020 Update**

The `map()` call can now be made even simpler by using ES6's arrow functions.

```
var textValues = $('.myClass').map((i, el) => el.innerText.trim()).get();
```

Note, however, that this will not work in IE. You will need to use the method in the first example if you require legacy browser support.

Comment: I also reached same code as you. `var textValues = $("li").map(function(){ return $(this).text(); }).get().join(",");`

Comment: dear reader, [docs](https://api.jquery.com/map/) will help to understand further. also note `.trim()`

Answer (score 1):

Simply concat the text inside `.each`. Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3bkyqqe/2/)

Here is modified jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
    var names = '';
    $('.myClass').each(function(index, obj) {
        names += $(this).text() +',';
    });
    alert(names);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of $(this)..!

```
var string = null;

$('.myClass').each(function(index, obj){
    // do something
    string += $(this).text();
});
```