# Using JQuery "Append" function, how to add same string to all divs with same class? (Only works once)

Tags: jquery, append

Using JQuery Append i want to fill a div with HTML, same for all instances of same class on the page.

**HTML**

```
Text
<div class="custom-content"></div>
Text
<div class="custom-content"></div>
Text
<div class="custom-content"></div>
Text
```

**JQuery:**

```
    <script>
      if ($(window).width() < 500) {
  $(".custom-content").append("<script>document.write('Small');<\/script>");
} else {
  $(".custom-content").append("<script>document.write('Large');<\/script>");
}
    </script>
```

I'm expecting "Large" or "Small" to show up on all 3 divs like so:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
Text
<div class="custom-content">Large</div>
Text
<div class="custom-content">Large</div>
Text
<div class="custom-content">Large</div>
Text
```

Only when i duplicate the script 3 times it does what i expect which is a bad solution.

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/MichaelROS/pen/QWwgXEB

What can i do? Please don't suggest using a different function than Append.

**Note: the code is very long it doesn't just write 1 word i did that to illustrate the problem which is already present in this example.**

Comment: Can't seem to replicate this problem - [Codepen.io to demonstrate](https://codepen.io/_Light/pen/RwNgQMr)

Comment: I'm sorry i simplified the code too much to simplify the question and it solved the issue. I now included a less simplified version. Can you look back? The issue must be with escaping script closing tag maybe?
Note. The script appended is much longer it doesn't just say a word.

Comment: try using `.each()` Example 
`$('.custom-content').each(function(){
    $(this).append('Content Here to Append');
});`

Comment: @YashKaranke it adds it 3 times to the last DIV see https://codepen.io/MichaelROS/pen/zYxzJbR

Answer (score 0):

The important point is loop.
Story: Get elements which has a this class. Then make an loop. And add child for each element.

At this point there is different solution.

I give you a few keys:
- `jQuery.each function`
- `document.getElementsByClassName`

Here is a similar question.
[jQuery .text() multiple elements same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559846/jquery-text-multiple-elements-same-class)

I hope i could help

Comment: I will try if i can't find other way. I was hoping there's a simple way to target all divs without having to do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp which states:

> The `write()` method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will **delete all existing HTML.**

(Emphasis mine) It's only being called the first time, because after that, the document no longer contains the executing code. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but `document.write` probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: The real code isn't a document .write it's just to illustrate it doesn't work. it's a remote script.

Comment: What other method can i use to test append?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. It **is appending** the script tags just fine it's just **not executing** the script inside of them. So i came with a different approach:

**NEW HTML**

```
Text
<div class="custom-content"><script>customtag();</script></div>
Text
<div class="custom-content"><script>customtag();</script></div>
Text
<div class="custom-content"><script>customtag();</script></div>
Text
```

**NEW JS:**

```
function customtag() {
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
document.write('Small');
} else {
document.write('Large');
}
}
```