# Get child elements one by one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I print the div's child elements one by one?

HTML:

```
<div>
   <a></a>
   <a></a>
   <a></a>
</div>
```

I am able to get all elements but not one by one. The goal is to be able to loop through each of the item and save everything into the array.

This line can print all div children elements:

```
$("#types > div > div").text()
```

But I would like to have something like this:

```
["txt1","text2","text3"]
```

Comment: so use map()....

Comment: Or, [jQuery .text() multiple elements same class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28559846/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.children()` to get the child elements, and iterate over them.

```
$("#types > div > div").children().each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

Identify the parent element that you want to get the children's text from, whether you use an ID or a classname

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById('parentElementId')
```

or use the following:

```
var parentElement = document.querySelector('.parentElementClassname'); //gets first matching parent with this classname.
```

Once you have your parent element reference, query for all children that are divs as:

```
var divElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll('div'); 
// Will return a
// HTMLNodeList of all child nodes that are of type div 
// starting from the top level recursively to the inner 
// divs in order from the top to the last div node within the parent
// In short it gets all divs ordered from top level div to the 
// innermost div from first child to last child that is of type div 
// then ordered by child level as arranged in the parentDiv
```

or direct div children elements as in:

```
var divElements = document.querySelectorAll('.parentElementClassname > div')
```

or

```
var divElements = var divElements = document.querySelectorAll('#parentElementID > div') // first level divs only
```

Remember you can use as many `'> div'` as the nesting levels you want let say I want all divs nested upto 2 levels deep then I will do

```
var divElements = var divElements = document.querySelectorAll('#parentElementID > div > div')
```

Lastly loop through the nodelist(`divElements`) to get your element's text in order of their occurence using a forEach

```
var arrayOfTextsFromChildrenDivs = [];

divElements.forEach(function(el){
   arrayOfText.push(el.innerText)
})
```

That's the general idea using Vanilla JS, any edits and corrections will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's map to loop over and make an array.

```js
console.log($("div > a").map(function(x, elem) { return $(elem).text(); }).get())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <a>1</a>
   <a>2</a>
   <a>3</a>
</div>
```